# Grammatical Gender þe þæt

Tags: grammatical-gender

When the nominative articles for masculine and feminine nouns were exchanged for þe and cases for nouns were lost, it would make sense for masculine and feminine to become a common gender like in various Germanic languages.
But neuter would still have þæt to be an article for neuter nouns. Like: That land belongs to the man; that child is rude.
Why would neuter be lost?

Comment: Why was neuter be kept in the Scandinavian languages? That seems a less likely outcome to me than losing all three genders. Note that the gender system involved a ***lot*** more than just definite articles. There are adjective endings and noun declinations as well.

Comment: I believe the standard account is that loss of gender distinctions occurred after m/f sgl *se/siu* regularized as *Þe/Þiu*.

Comment: @StoneyB but that would only rid English of the masc/fem differenciation. Not the neuter gender

Comment: Well, *þæt* becomes demonstrative, as it is today. It's not actually **lost;** it's changed its function.

Comment: No; the m/f/n were still distinct: *Þe/Þiu/Þæt* in the nominative, *Þone/Þa/Þæt* in the accusative. In other cases, m&n are identical, contrasting with f. ... That at least is the account in [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt209murruoft#page/256/mode/2up). Still later, when case was lost, *Þe* was bracketed off as the determinative and *Þæt* was bracketed off as the demonstrative, functions which all the forms had previously shared.